# Excel VBA: Import CSV and renaming the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have the following macro in MS Excel: I can click on a macro-button and can then select a .csv-file and the macro imports the files in the right format into a new sheet with the name "test" and a counting number.

It would be really nice for me if the new sheets have the same name as the .csv-file - does anyone know how to implement this here?

```
Sub GetCSVList()
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    ''Start in
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Test"
    .Show
End With

For Each fname In dlgOpen.SelectedItems
    ImportCSV fname
Next
End Sub



Sub ImportCSV(fname)
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = "test" & Worksheets.Count + 1

With ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Test" & Worksheets.Count + 1
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    '.UseListObject = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you test or run debug with your code? If not, try it and test what you have in `fname`

Comment: `ws.Name = fname` instead of `ws.Name = "test" & Worksheets.Count + 1`?  (But obviously you will first need to check that `fname` is valid as a sheet name - there are several limitations to what is / isn't allowed as a sheet name.)

Comment: I tried 'ws.Name = fname' before, but it only gives me a runetime error 1004 (name for sheet is invalid) - the name should be fine (it's "03.10.csv")

Comment: Setting the sheet name to `"03.10.csv"` shouldn't have caused any issues.  But on looking at your code again, `fname` is probably the fully-qualified name (i.e. with path, and the "\" wouldn't be valid in a worksheet name), so try `ws.Name = Mid(fname, InStrRev(fname, "\") + 1)`

Comment: perfect, that worked! is it also possible to delete the ".csv" at the end? Thank you very much!!

Comment: If it is **always** `.csv`, then I would just add a line after that saying `ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - 4)`

Comment: perfect, thank you!!